# Display highlighted/selected best answers in profile

Tags: feature-request, profile-page

When someone sees a profile, they see the most voted or recent Answers. However, those aren't necessarily authors best answers, they are just searched a lot. Wouldn't it be cool to have a display of authors selected best answers on their profile **without needing to insert them into *About me***.

Authors best answers is a selection of answers made by the profile owner that is shown on their profile.

I suggest to either add a subtab switch to *Answers* panel or create a new dedicated panel. *(Can be highlighted, selected, etc.. you name it)*
[image]

*Note that this might be applied to Questions author is most proud of as well.*

Comment: How would your "best" answers be determined, if not by votes?

Comment: @CodyGray By my own selection. I consider "best" answers those I spent most time on or other valuable answers for topics that might not be searched that much. Those could be viewed as well as *Answers I am most proud of*.

Comment: Well, that sounds like a lot of drudge work! :-) It isn't exactly the same, but you do know that if you create a profile on the Jobs site, you can hand-pick your favorite Q&A to place in your Developer CV, right?

Answer (score 3):

You can already do this manually in your About Me section, e.g. like [this user](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/63550/peter-mortensen). This even allows you to format it in your own way if you desire so, and it is visible immediately to *every* user visiting your profile.

[image]

Comment: Well, yeah. That's why I said `Without needing to insert them into About me`. Clearly, the About me wasn't intended for this as it is quite cumbersome to achieve that. I am looking for something more user-friendly.